# How to handle Drag and Drop Properly using PYQT QAbstractItemModel

Tags: pyqt, qtreeview, qtreewidget, qabstractitemmodel, qtreewidgetitem

Here is a code I ended up after two days of TreeView/Model madness. The subject appeared to be much more broad than I thought. I barely can spend so much time creating a singe widget. Anyway. The drag-and-drop functionality of TreeView items has been enabled. But other than few interesting printout there is not much there. The double click on an item allows the user to enter a new item name which won't be picked up.

## EDITED A DAY LATER WITH A REVISED CODE.

### **It is now by 90% functional tool.**

The user can manipulate the TreeView items by drag and dropping, creating/duplicating/deleting and renaming. The TreeView items are representing the directories or folders in hierarchical fashion before they are created on a drive by hitting 'Print' button (instead of os.makedirs() the tool still simply prints each directory as a string.
I would say I am pretty happy with the result. Thanks to *hackyday* and to everyone who responded and helped with my questions.

A few last wishes...

#### A wish number 01:

1. I wish the PrintOut() method would use a more elegant smarter function to loop through the TreeView items to build a dictionary that is being passed to make_dirs_from_dict() method.

#### A wish number 02:

1. I wish deleting the items would be more stable. By some unknown reason a tool crashes on third/fourth Delete button clicks. So far, I was unable to trace the problem down.

A wish number 03:
3. I wish everyone the best and thanks for your help :

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from copy import deepcopy
import cPickle    

class TreeItem(object):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):

        self.name = QtCore.QString(name)       
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []       
        self.setParent(parent)

    def setParent(self, parent):
        if parent != None:
            self.parent = parent
            self.parent.appendChild(self)
        else:     self.parent = None

    def appendChild(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

    def childAtRow(self, row):
        if len(self.children)>row: 
            return self.children[row]

    def rowOfChild(self, child):       
        for i, item in enumerate(self.children):
            if item == child:  return i
        return -1

    def removeChild(self, row):
        value = self.children[row]
        self.children.remove(value)
        return True

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.children) 

class TreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self):

        QtCore.QAbstractItemModel.__init__(self)

        self.columns = 1
        self.clickedItem=None

        self.root = TreeItem('root', None) 
        levelA = TreeItem('levelA', self.root)
        levelB = TreeItem('levelB', levelA)
        levelC1 = TreeItem('levelC1', levelB)
        levelC2 = TreeItem('levelC2', levelB)
        levelC3 = TreeItem('levelC3', levelB)
        levelD = TreeItem('levelD', levelC3)

        levelE = TreeItem('levelE', levelD)
        levelF = TreeItem('levelF', levelE)

    def nodeFromIndex(self, index):
        return index.internalPointer() if index.isValid() else self.root

    def index(self, row, column, parent):        
        node = self.nodeFromIndex(parent)
        return self.createIndex(row, column, node.childAtRow(row))

    def parent(self, child):
        # print '\n parent(child)', child  # PyQt4.QtCore.QModelIndex
        if not child.isValid():  return QModelIndex()
        node = self.nodeFromIndex(child)       
        if node is None:   return QModelIndex()
        parent = node.parent           
        if parent is None:      return QModelIndex()       
        grandparent = parent.parent

        if grandparent==None:    return QModelIndex()

        row = grandparent.rowOfChild(parent)    
        assert row != - 1

        return self.createIndex(row, 0, parent)

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        node = self.nodeFromIndex(parent)
        if node is None: return 0
        return len(node)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return self.columns

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
            return QVariant()               
        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return QVariant(int(Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignLeft))       
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:   
            return QVariant()                   
        node = self.nodeFromIndex(index)       
        if index.column() == 0:     
            return QVariant(node.name)       
        elif index.column() == 1:   
            return QVariant(node.state)       
        elif index.column() == 2:   
            return QVariant(node.description)
        else:   return QVariant()

    def supportedDropActions(self):
        return Qt.CopyAction | Qt.MoveAction

    def flags(self, index):
        defaultFlags = QAbstractItemModel.flags(self, index)       
        if index.isValid():  return Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags           
        else:   return Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags  

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            if value.toString() and len(value.toString())>0: 
                self.nodeFromIndex(index).name = value.toString()
                self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True

    def mimeTypes(self):
        return ['bstream', 'text/xml']

    def mimeData(self, indexes):

        mimedata = QtCore.QMimeData()
        bstream = cPickle.dumps(self.nodeFromIndex(indexes[0]))
        mimedata.setData('bstream', bstream)
        return mimedata

    def dropMimeData(self, mimedata, action, row, column, parentIndex):

        if action == Qt.IgnoreAction: return True  

        droppedNode=cPickle.loads(str(mimedata.data('bstream')))

        droppedIndex = self.createIndex(row, column, droppedNode)

        parentNode = self.nodeFromIndex(parentIndex)

        newNode = deepcopy(droppedNode)
        newNode.setParent(parentNode)

        self.insertRow(len(parentNode)-1, parentIndex)

        self.emit(SIGNAL("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"), parentIndex, parentIndex)

        return True

    def insertRow(self, row, parent):
        return self.insertRows(row, 1, parent)
    def insertRows(self, row, count, parent):
        self.beginInsertRows(parent, row, (row + (count - 1)))
        self.endInsertRows()
        return True

    def removeRow(self, row, parentIndex):
        return self.removeRows(row, 1, parentIndex)

    def removeRows(self, row, count, parentIndex):
        self.beginRemoveRows(parentIndex, row, row)
        node = self.nodeFromIndex(parentIndex)
        node.removeChild(row)
        self.endRemoveRows()       
        return True


class GUI(QtGui.QDialog):
    def build(self, myWindow):
        myWindow.resize(600, 400)
        self.myWidget = QWidget(myWindow)        
        self.boxLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.myWidget)

        self.treeView = QtGui.QTreeView()

        self.treeModel = TreeModel()
        self.treeView.setModel(self.treeModel)
        self.treeView.expandAll()
        self.treeView.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.treeView.connect(self.treeView.model(), SIGNAL("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"), self.onDataChanged)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.treeView, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked (QModelIndex)"),  self.treeItemClicked)
        self.boxLayout.addWidget(self.treeView)


        self.PrintButton= QtGui.QPushButton("Print")  
        self.PrintButton.clicked.connect(self.PrintOut) 
        self.boxLayout.addWidget(self.PrintButton)

        self.DeleteButton= QtGui.QPushButton("Delete")  
        self.DeleteButton.clicked.connect(self.DeleteLevel) 
        self.boxLayout.addWidget(self.DeleteButton)

        self.insertButton= QtGui.QPushButton("Insert")  
        self.insertButton.clicked.connect(self.insertLevel) 
        self.boxLayout.addWidget(self.insertButton)

        self.duplicateButton= QtGui.QPushButton("Duplicate")  
        self.duplicateButton.clicked.connect(self.duplicateLevel) 
        self.boxLayout.addWidget(self.duplicateButton)

        myWindow.setCentralWidget(self.myWidget)


    def make_dirs_from_dict(self, dirDict, current_dir='/'):
        for key, val in dirDict.items():
            #os.mkdir(os.path.join(current_dir, key))
            print "\t\t Creating directory: ", os.path.join(current_dir, key)
            if type(val) == dict:
                self.make_dirs_from_dict(val, os.path.join(current_dir, key))

    def PrintOut(self):
        result_dict = {}
        for a1 in self.treeView.model().root.children:
            result_dict[str(a1.name)]={}
            for a2 in a1.children:
                result_dict[str(a1.name)][str(a2.name)]={}
                for a3 in a2.children:
                    result_dict[str(a1.name)][str(a2.name)][str(a3.name)]={}
                    for a4 in a3.children:
                        result_dict[ str(a1.name)][str(a2.name)][str(a3.name)][str(a4.name)]={}
                        for a5 in a4.children:
                            result_dict[ str(a1.name)][str(a2.name)][str(a3.name)][str(a4.name)][str(a5.name)]={}
                            for a6 in a5.children:
                                result_dict[str(a1.name)][str(a2.name)][str(a3.name)][str(a4.name)][str(a5.name)][str(a6.name)]={}
                                for a7 in a6.children:
                                    result_dict[str(a1.name)][str(a2.name)][str(a3.name)][str(a4.name)][str(a5.name)][str(a6.name)][str(a7.name)]={}


        self.make_dirs_from_dict(result_dict)                      


    def DeleteLevel(self):
        if len(self.treeView.selectedIndexes())==0: return

        currentIndex = self.treeView.selectedIndexes()[0]
        currentRow=currentIndex.row()
        currentColumn=currentIndex.column()
        currentNode = currentIndex.internalPointer()

        parentNode = currentNode.parent
        parentIndex = self.treeView.model().createIndex(currentRow, currentColumn, parentNode)
        print '\n\t\t\t CurrentNode:', currentNode.name, ', ParentNode:', currentNode.parent.name, ', currentColumn:', currentColumn, ', currentRow:', currentRow 

        # self.treeView.model().removeRow(len(parentNode)-1, parentIndex) 

        self.treeView.model().removeRows(currentRow, 1, parentIndex )

        #self.treeView.model().removeRow(len(parentNode), parentIndex)
        #self.treeView.model().emit(SIGNAL("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"), parentIndex, parentIndex) 

    def insertLevel(self):
        if len(self.treeView.selectedIndexes())==0: return

        currentIndex = self.treeView.selectedIndexes()[0]
        currentNode = currentIndex.internalPointer()
        newItem = TreeItem('Brand New', currentNode)
        self.treeView.model().insertRow(len(currentNode)-1, currentIndex)
        self.treeView.model().emit(SIGNAL("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"), currentIndex, currentIndex)   

    def duplicateLevel(self):
        if len(self.treeView.selectedIndexes())==0: return

        currentIndex = self.treeView.selectedIndexes()[0]
        currentRow=currentIndex.row()
        currentColumn=currentIndex.column()
        currentNode=currentIndex.internalPointer()

        parentNode=currentNode.parent
        parentIndex=self.treeView.model().createIndex(currentRow, currentColumn, parentNode)
        parentRow=parentIndex.row()
        parentColumn=parentIndex.column()

        newNode = deepcopy(currentNode)
        newNode.setParent(parentNode)

        self.treeView.model().insertRow(len(parentNode)-1, parentIndex)
        self.treeView.model().emit(SIGNAL("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"), parentIndex, parentIndex) 

        print '\n\t\t\t CurrentNode:', currentNode.name, ', ParentNode:', parentNode.name, ', currentColumn:', currentColumn, ', currentRow:', currentRow, ', parentColumn:', parentColumn, ', parentRow:', parentRow 
        self.treeView.update()
        self.treeView.expandAll()


    def treeItemClicked(self, index):
        print "\n clicked item ----------->", index.internalPointer().name

    def onDataChanged(self, indexA, indexB):
        print "\n onDataChanged NEVER TRIGGERED! ####################### \n ", index.internalPointer().name
        self.treeView.update(indexA)
        self.treeView.expandAll()
        self.treeView.expanded()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    myWindow = QMainWindow()
    myGui = GUI()
    myGui.build(myWindow)
    myWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Revised a posting completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not totally sure what you are trying to achieve, but it sounds like you want to retrieve the dragged item in the drop operation, and have double click save a new node name.

Firstly, you need to save the dragged item into the `mimeData`. Currently, you are only saving the string 'mimeData', which doesn't tell you much. The *mimeType* string that it is saved as (here I used 'bstream') can actually be anything. As long as it matches what you use to retrieve the data, and is in the list returned by the `mimeTypes` method of the model. To pass the object itself, you must first serialize it (you can convert your object to xml alternatively, if that was something you are planning on doing), since it is not a standard type for mime data.

In order for the data you enter to be saved you must re-implement the setData method of the model and define behaviour for `EditRole`.

The relevant methods:

```
def setData(self, index, value, role):
    if role == Qt.EditRole:
        self.nodeFromIndex(index).name = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True

def mimeTypes(self):
    return ['bstream', 'text/xml']

def mimeData(self, indexes):
    mimedata = QtCore.QMimeData()
    # assuming single dragged item ...
    # only pass the node name
    # mimedata.setData('text/xml', str(self.nodeFromIndex(indexes[0]).name))
    # pass the entire object
    bstream = cPickle.dumps(self.nodeFromIndex(indexes[0]))
    mimedata.setData('bstream', bstream)
    return mimedata

def dropMimeData(self, mimedata, action, row, column, parentIndex):

    if action == Qt.IgnoreAction: return True        

    parentNode = self.nodeFromIndex(parentIndex)

    # data = mimedata.data('text/xml')
    data = cPickle.loads(str(mimedata.data('bstream')))
    print '\n\t incoming row number:', row, ', incoming column:', column, \
        ', action:', action, ' mimedata: ', data.name

    print "\n\t Item's name on which drop occurred: ", parentNode.name, \
        ', number of its childred:', len(parentNode.children)

    if len(parentNode.children)>0: print '\n\t zero indexed child:', parentNode.children[0].name

    return True
```

EDIT:
That is a lot of code you updated, but I will oblige on the points you highlighted. Avoid calling `createIndex` outside of the model class. This is a protected method in Qt; Python doesn't enforce private/protected variables or methods, but when using a library from another language that does, I try to respect the intended organization of the classes, and access to them.

The purpose of the model is to provide an interface to your data. You should access it using the `index`, `data`, `parent` etc. public functions of the model. To get the parent of a given index, use that index's (or the model's) `parent` function, which will also return a QModelIndex. This way, you don't have to go through (or indeed know about) the internal structure of the data. This is what I did in the `deleteLevel` method.

From the qt [docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#model-classes):

> To ensure that the representation of the data is kept separate from the way it is  accessed, the concept of a model index is introduced. Each piece of information that can be obtained via a model is represented by a model index... only the model needs to know how to obtain data, and the type of data managed by the model can be defined fairly generally.

Also, you can use recursion to simplify the print method.

```
def printOut(self):
    result_dict = dictify(self.treeView.model().root)
    self.make_dirs_from_dict(result_dict)  

def deleteLevel(self):
    if len(self.treeView.selectedIndexes()) == 0: 
        return

    currentIndex = self.treeView.selectedIndexes()[0]
    self.treeView.model().removeRow(currentIndex.row(), currentIndex.parent())
```

I had this separate from class

```
def dictify(node):
    kids = {}
    for child in node.children:
        kids.update(dictify(child)) 
    return {str(node.name): kids}
```

Comment: Thanks  Hacky! I have revisited the code with the suggestions you posted. Please take a look at it! The tool is working pretty stable except the Delete row method crashes it once in a while. No cause yet determined why that happens.

Comment: Thanks for dictify(). I noticed a similar recursion yesterday in one of the examples. Great logic!     I'm not sure how to avoid calling createIndex() method outside of the model class. I realize it can be consider 'intrusive'.

Comment: I expanded my explanation, I hope it makes more sense.