# PyQt5 tree model: drag&drop problem dragging from back to front within the same level

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I tried the code from [How to handle Drag and Drop Properly using PYQT QAbstractItemModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22020091/how-to-handle-drag-and-drop-properly-using-pyqt-qabstractitemmodel/66864441#66864441)

and found that every time I drag, I can only insert the dragged node to the end of a parent. This is because appendChild() is called in the setParent() method. Based on the above code, I tried to modify the setParent() method to insert the dragged node into the placement point (rather than the end). The revised setParent() method is given as:

```
    def setParent1(self, position, parent):

        if parent != None:

            # if self.parent.name == parent.name:  # 解决从后往前移动出问题，时行时不行
            #     row0 = self.parent.rowOfChild(self)
            #     if position < row0:
            #         print(f"yes,row0={row0}, position={position}")
            #         parent.children[row0] = parent.children[row0 - 1]

            self.parent = parent
            self.parent.insertChild(position, self)
        else:
            self.parent = None
```

together with the insertChild() method as:

```
    def insertChild(self, position, child):
        if position < 0 | position > self.__len__():
            return False
        self.children.insert(position, child)
```

When the above method is adopted, I can insert the dragged node into the placement point, but for the children of the same level, if you drag the lower child to the front, there will be problems. For example, the original Tree is as follows:

```
level A
    level B1
    level B2
    level B3
    level B4
```

If I drag level B3 before level B1, the expected result will become as follows:

```
level A
  level B3
  level B1
  level B2
  level B4
```

However, the actual result becomes:

```
level A
  level B3
  level B1
  level B3
  level B4
```

In addition, when dragging from the back to the front, sometimes the following error will appear:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/treeModel_drag&drop_eg3.py", line 114, in parent
    parent = node.parent
AttributeError:'list_iterator' object has no attribute'parent'
```

But if I drag level B1 backward, for example after level B3, no error will be reported and the result will be correct:

```
level A
  level B2
  level B3
  level B1
  level B4
```

The following is the complete code, I hope someone can help me, thanks

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, os
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from copy import deepcopy
import pickle


class TreeItem(object):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):

        self.name = str(name)
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []
        self.setParent(parent)
        # self.setParent1(self.childCount(), parent)  #

    def childCount(self):
        return len(self.children)

    def setParent(self, parent):
        if parent != None:
            self.parent = parent
            self.parent.appendChild(self)
        else:
            self.parent = None

    def setParent1(self, position, parent):

        if parent != None:

            # if self.parent.name == parent.name:  # 解决从后往前移动出问题，时行时不行
            #     row0 = self.parent.rowOfChild(self)
            #     if position < row0:
            #         print(f"yes,row0={row0}, position={position}")
            #         parent.children[row0] = parent.children[row0 - 1]

            self.parent = parent
            self.parent.insertChild(position, self)
        else:
            self.parent = None

    def appendChild(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)

    def insertChild(self, position, child):
        if position < 0 | position > self.__len__():
            return False
        self.children.insert(position, child)

    def childAtRow(self, row):
        if len(self.children)>row:
            return self.children[row]

    def rowOfChild(self, child):
        for i, item in enumerate(self.children):
            if item == child:
                return i
        return -1

    def removeChild(self, row):
        value = self.children[row]
        self.children.remove(value)
        return True

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.children)

class TreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):

    def __init__(self):

        QAbstractItemModel.__init__(self)

        self.columns = 1
        self.clickedItem=None

        self.root = TreeItem('root', None)
        levelA = TreeItem('levelA', self.root)
        levelB = TreeItem('levelB', levelA)
        levelC1 = TreeItem('levelC1', levelB)
        levelC2 = TreeItem('levelC2', levelB)
        levelC3 = TreeItem('levelC3', levelB)
        levelD = TreeItem('levelD', levelC3)

        levelE = TreeItem('levelE', levelD)
        levelF = TreeItem('levelF', levelE)

    def nodeFromIndex(self, index):
        return index.internalPointer() if index.isValid() else self.root

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        node = self.nodeFromIndex(parent)
        return self.createIndex(row, column, node.childAtRow(row))

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QModelIndex()
        node = self.nodeFromIndex(index)
        if node is None:
            return QModelIndex()
        parent = node.parent
        if parent is None:
            return QModelIndex()
        grandparent = parent.parent

        if grandparent==None:
            return QModelIndex()

        row = grandparent.rowOfChild(parent)
        assert row != - 1
        return self.createIndex(row, 0, parent)

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        node = self.nodeFromIndex(parent)
        if node is None: return 0
        return len(node)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return self.columns

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
            return QVariant()
        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            return QVariant(int(Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignLeft))
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant()
        node = self.nodeFromIndex(index)
        if index.column() == 0:
            return QVariant(node.name)
        elif index.column() == 1:
            return QVariant(node.state)
        elif index.column() == 2:
            return QVariant(node.description)
        else:   return QVariant()

    def supportedDropActions(self):
        return Qt.MoveAction  # | Qt.CopyAction

    def flags(self, index):
        defaultFlags = QAbstractItemModel.flags(self, index)
        if index.isValid():
            return Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled \
                   | Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags
        else:
            return Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled | defaultFlags

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            if value.toString() and len(value.toString()) > 0:
                self.nodeFromIndex(index).name = value.toString()
                self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True

    def mimeTypes(self):
        return ['bstream', 'text/xml']

    def mimeData(self, indexes):

        mimedata = QMimeData()
        bstream = pickle.dumps(self.nodeFromIndex(indexes[0]))
        mimedata.setData('bstream', bstream)
        return mimedata

    def dropMimeData(self, mimedata, action, row, column, parentIndex):

        if action == Qt.IgnoreAction:
            return True

        droppedNode=pickle.loads(mimedata.data('bstream'))

        #
        beginRow = -1
        if row != -1:  # 表示
            print("case 1: ROW IS NOT -1, meaning inserting in between, above or below an existing node")
            beginRow = row
        elif parentIndex.isValid():
            print("case 2: PARENT IS VALID, inserting ONTO something since row was not -1, "
                  "beginRow becomes 0 because we want to "
                  "insert it at the beginning of this parents children")
            beginRow = parentIndex.row()
        else:
            print("case 3: PARENT IS INVALID, inserting to root, "
                  "can change to 0 if you want it to appear at the top")
            beginRow = self.rowCount(QModelIndex())
        print(f"row={row}, beginRow={beginRow}")
        # ************尝试使得插入点为拖拽落点
        droppedIndex = self.createIndex(row, column, droppedNode)
        parentNode = self.nodeFromIndex(parentIndex)
        newNode = deepcopy(droppedNode)
        #

        # newNode.setParent(parentNode)  
        newNode.setParent1(beginRow, parentNode)
        self.dataChanged.emit(parentIndex, parentIndex)
        return True

    def insertRow(self, row, parent):
        return self.insertRows(row, 1, parent)
    def insertRows(self, row, count, parent):
        self.beginInsertRows(parent, row, (row + (count - 1)))

        self.endInsertRows()
        return True

    def removeRow(self, row, parentIndex):
        return self.removeRows(row, 1, parentIndex)

    def removeRows(self, row, count, parentIndex):
        self.beginRemoveRows(parentIndex, row, row)
        node = self.nodeFromIndex(parentIndex)
        node.removeChild(row)
        self.endRemoveRows()
        return True


class GUI(QDialog):
    def build(self, myWindow):
        myWindow.resize(600, 400)
        self.myWidget = QWidget(myWindow)
        self.boxLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.myWidget)

        self.treeView = QTreeView()
        self.treeView.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)

        self.treeModel = TreeModel()
        self.treeView.setModel(self.treeModel)
        self.treeView.expandAll()
        self.treeView.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        # self.treeView.connect(self.treeView.model(), pyqtSignal("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"), self.onDataChanged)
        # QObject.connect(self.treeView, pyqtSignal("clicked (QModelIndex)"),  self.treeItemClicked)
        self.boxLayout.addWidget(self.treeView)


        self.PrintButton= QPushButton("Print")
        self.PrintButton.clicked.connect(self.PrintOut)
        self.boxLayout.addWidget(self.PrintButton)

        self.DeleteButton= QPushButton("Delete")
        self.DeleteButton.clicked.connect(self.DeleteLevel)
        self.boxLayout.addWidget(self.DeleteButton)

        self.insertButton= QPushButton("Insert")
        self.insertButton.clicked.connect(self.insertLevel)
        self.boxLayout.addWidget(self.insertButton)

        self.duplicateButton= QPushButton("Duplicate")
        self.duplicateButton.clicked.connect(self.duplicateLevel)
        self.boxLayout.addWidget(self.duplicateButton)

        myWindow.setCentralWidget(self.myWidget)


    def make_dirs_from_dict(self, dirDict, current_dir='/'):
        for key, val in dirDict.items():
            #os.mkdir(os.path.join(current_dir, key))
            print("\t\t Creating directory: ", os.path.join(current_dir, key))
            if type(val) == dict:
                self.make_dirs_from_dict(val, os.path.join(current_dir, key))

    def PrintOut(self):
        result_dict = {}
        for a1 in self.treeView.model().root.children:
            result_dict[str(a1.name)]={}
            for a2 in a1.children:
                result_dict[str(a1.name)][str(a2.name)]={}
                for a3 in a2.children:
                    result_dict[str(a1.name)][str(a2.name)][str(a3.name)]={}
                    for a4 in a3.children:
                        result_dict[ str(a1.name)][str(a2.name)][str(a3.name)][str(a4.name)]={}
                        for a5 in a4.children:
                            result_dict[ str(a1.name)][str(a2.name)][str(a3.name)][str(a4.name)][str(a5.name)]={}
                            for a6 in a5.children:
                                result_dict[str(a1.name)][str(a2.name)][str(a3.name)][str(a4.name)][str(a5.name)][str(a6.name)]={}
                                for a7 in a6.children:
                                    result_dict[str(a1.name)][str(a2.name)][str(a3.name)][str(a4.name)][str(a5.name)][str(a6.name)][str(a7.name)]={}


        self.make_dirs_from_dict(result_dict)


    def DeleteLevel(self):
        if len(self.treeView.selectedIndexes())==0: return

        currentIndex = self.treeView.selectedIndexes()[0]
        currentRow=currentIndex.row()
        currentColumn=currentIndex.column()
        currentNode = currentIndex.internalPointer()

        parentNode = currentNode.parent
        parentIndex = self.treeView.model().createIndex(currentRow, currentColumn, parentNode)
        print('\n\t\t\t CurrentNode:', currentNode.name, ', ParentNode:', currentNode.parent.name, ', currentColumn:', currentColumn, ', currentRow:', currentRow)

        # self.treeView.model().removeRow(len(parentNode)-1, parentIndex)

        self.treeView.model().removeRows(currentRow, 1, parentIndex )

        #self.treeView.model().removeRow(len(parentNode), parentIndex)
        #self.treeView.model().emit(SIGNAL("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"), parentIndex, parentIndex)

    def insertLevel(self):
        if len(self.treeView.selectedIndexes())==0: return

        currentIndex = self.treeView.selectedIndexes()[0]
        currentNode = currentIndex.internalPointer()
        newItem = TreeItem('Brand New', currentNode)
        self.treeView.model().insertRow(len(currentNode)-1, currentIndex)
        self.treeView.model().emit(pyqtSignal("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"), currentIndex, currentIndex)

    def duplicateLevel(self):
        if len(self.treeView.selectedIndexes())==0: return

        currentIndex = self.treeView.selectedIndexes()[0]
        currentRow=currentIndex.row()
        currentColumn=currentIndex.column()
        currentNode=currentIndex.internalPointer()

        parentNode=currentNode.parent
        parentIndex=self.treeView.model().createIndex(currentRow, currentColumn, parentNode)
        parentRow=parentIndex.row()
        parentColumn=parentIndex.column()

        newNode = deepcopy(currentNode)
        newNode.setParent(parentNode)

        self.treeView.model().insertRow(len(parentNode)-1, parentIndex)
        self.treeView.model().emit(pyqtSignal("dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)"), parentIndex, parentIndex)

        print('\n\t\t\t CurrentNode:', currentNode.name, ', ParentNode:', parentNode.name, ', currentColumn:', currentColumn, ', currentRow:', currentRow, ', parentColumn:', parentColumn, ', parentRow:', parentRow)
        self.treeView.update()
        self.treeView.expandAll()


    def treeItemClicked(self, index):
        print("\n clicked item ----------->", index.internalPointer().name)

    def onDataChanged(self, indexA, indexB):
        print("\n onDataChanged NEVER TRIGGERED! ####################### \n ", indexB.internalPointer().name)
        self.treeView.update(indexA)
        self.treeView.expandAll()
        self.treeView.expanded()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    myWindow = QMainWindow()
    myGui = GUI()
    myGui.build(myWindow)
    myWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of working, I figure out the problem, here the following is the running sequence when you perform a drag&drop operation in a Tree view:

1. After you drag&drop some nodes in a tree, the indexes of the nodes are passed to the **mimeData()** method, in which the corresponding node of each index is encapsulated in QMimeData(),
2. Then the program will call **dropMimeData(self, data, action, row, column, parentIndex)** Method, in this method, first you need to parse out each dragged node from the **data**, and then to calculate the inserting position according to parameters **row, column, parentIndex**, and then insert each dragged node into the parent node corresponding to **parentIndex**.
3. The third step is that PyQt5 will automatically call the **removeRows()** method of the model to remove the node that was originally dragged. remember, the automatically called **removeRows** method can only remember the initial position of the node being moved.

It is precisely because of the above sequence of inserting first and then deleting, that if the child node belonging to the same parent node is dragged and dragged from back to front, then when the removeRows method is automatically called, the position of the node that should be removed has changed, which will make the removal error